# How can i remove cookie-header from BackgroundDownloader?

Tags: c#, uwp

When i send request with BackgroundDownloader added header with cookie.
Why he added and how remove this?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the cookie with the [SetRequestHeader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounddownloader.setrequestheader) method in the BackgroundDownloader.
The Cookie is sent in the "Cookie" HTTP header, so you can overwrite this:

```
bgDownloader.SetRequestHeader("Cookie", "dummy=0");
```

I think some built in cache stores these cookies.

Readings: [BackgroundDownloader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207126)

**Edit:** You can't set empty or whitespace string to the Cookie header. Maybe you could send some dummy content, but the server could fail while parsing it.